# MQTT Subscribe / OTA Update Deep Sleep / ESP32 / FreeRTOS

Tags: mqtt, esp32, aws-iot, freertos

The goal is to receive messages over MQTT in an IoT device that comes out of deep sleep periodically. The exact same considerations exist for OTA update as for any other parameter update. In my case, ultimately, I want to use this for both.

---

### Progress

*It runs*

The device wakes for about 15 seconds. If during that time, I publish a bunch of messages to the relevant topic, the message arrived successfully. Inside the AWS console I can publish to :

```
$aws/things/<device-name>/shadow/update/delta

{
    "state":{
        "desired":{
            "output":true
        }
    }
}
```

And the delta callback function runs for 'output'. Great but no practical use to anyone.

---

*IoT Job*

I created a custom AWS IoT job in the console in an effort to overcome the problem. My thinking was that it might retain the message to ensure delivery. I've been running the job for the past half hour but so far nothing has come through. It had a 20 timeout but is still stuck in queued, not even in progress yet... So, there is clearly a flaw in this approach.

---

*AWS CLI test*

Just for completeness, I've attempted to fire off the MQTT message from the console. It has the benefit that you can specify the QOS, (in theory) ensuring that it gets delivered at least once.

```
aws iot-data publish --topic "$aws/things/<device-name>/shadow/update/delta" --qos 1 --payload file://Downloads/outputTrue.json --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out
```

But oddly this didn't seem to work at all. I didn't see the message arrive at the broker at all: subscribing in the console test.

---

Comment: Leaving a message in the queue is the correct solution, but it seems like you need to fix your MQTT connection to AWS. Do you shut it down before going to sleep?

Comment: What QOS are you subscribing with from the client?

Comment: Subscribing qos=1. The session is set to persistent. Any ideas how the mqtt connection needs to be configured for queue to work?

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT Core does not support retained messages, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html).

> The MQTT specification provides a provision for the publisher to request that the broker retain the last message sent to a topic and send it to all future topic subscribers. **AWS IoT doesn't support retained messages. If a request is made to retain messages, the connection is disconnected.**

As the wake-up times are perriodically, a possible approach could be to publish the next wake-up slot of your device in a separate topic where your backend is listening to. Your backend will then publish the desired information to your device-topic once the slot opens up.

Of course this approach is quite fragile concerning latency and network stability.

Comment: The question doesn't have anything to do with retained messages.

Comment: As of 2022-01-01 (not sure how far back)  IotCore DOES support retained messages:
--- quote: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html
AWS IoT Core supports the RETAIN flag described in MQTT v3.1.1. When a client sets the RETAIN flag on an MQTT message that it publishes, AWS IoT Core saves the message. It can then be sent to new subscribers, retrieved by calling the GetRetainedMessage operation, and viewed in the AWS IoT console. AWS IoT Core stores retained messages for three years after the last time they were updated or accessed.

Answer (score 0):

Time to share the answer I found from piecing together numerous posts and reaching out to the very helpful AWS support team. This link is the one that really covers it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/jobs-devices.html#jobs-workflow-device-online

My summarised pseudo code is :

```
1. init() & connect() to mqtt as before.
2. Subscribe to the following topics & create callback function for each:

  a. Get pending.   
  b. Notify next.    
  c. Get next.
  d. Update rejected.   
  e. Update accepted.   

3.  Create Publish topics:

  a.    Get pending.
  b.    Get Next.

4. Pending topics = optional. But necessary to handle many tasks and select between them. 
5. Aws-iot-jobs-describe() to publish a request for the next job. It links up to the notify next callback (somehow). 
6. In the callback, grab job document, execute job & report Success / Failure. 
7. Done.
```

There is a helpful example in esp-aws-iot/samples/linux/jobs-samples/jobs_sample.c. You need to copy some of the constants over from the sample aws_iot_config.h.

Once you've done all of this, you are able to use AWS Jobs to manage your OTA roll out, which was the original intent.